# External CSS file is not loading in Codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Here is my view file code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css" media="all">
    <title>Workctrl Assignment</title>
</head>
```

**Here is my controller file code**

```php
<?php
class Regis extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('registration');
    }
}

?>
```

**Folder Structure**
[image: Folder Structure]

I also autolad 'url' helper

**Error**

> http://localhost/Codeigniter_Project/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: We see your css folder in the directory image, but not the style.css file. Can you expand that and confirm the file exists there?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: style.css file is already there @James.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if accessing this URL through the browser opens the file correctly?

Pay attention to the folder and file names. For it to work in the code, it must work properly in the browser.

Like the link below:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).